# Xamarin iOS project Info.plist issues during submission on App Store

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am developing project which use the following permissions in `Info.plist`: `NSCameraUsageDescription`, 
`NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`, `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription`, `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription`, `NSCalendarsUsageDescription`. App can browse photos library or take a picture. After the deployment process for submission on App Store I get the info:

```
The app's Info.plist file should contain a NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data.
The app's Info.plist file should contain a NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data.
```

In my app I don't use or ask user for location permission. Moreover I use the NuGet packages: `Xamarin.Essentials`, Forms, `Plugin.Permissions`. How can I workaround this issue with location permissions to avoid placing this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing that you can do to workaround the problem aside from removing plugins.

And there are no reasons to do something like that as the end-user won't see any difference unless you ask for the location in the app's code. Info.plist is not visible to the end user in any way including through the app listing.